# Summing up prior rows contingent on ID #'s in R, for loop vs apply

Tags: r, for-loop, sum, apply

I have a dataframe of xyz coordinates of units in 5 different boxes, all 4x4x8 so 128 total possible locations. The units are all different lengths. So even though I know the coordinates of the unit (3 units in, 2 left, and 1 up) I don't know the exact location of the unit in the box (12' in, 14' left, 30' up?). The z dimension corresponds to length and is the dimension I am interested in.

My instinct is to run a for loop summing values, but that is generally not the most efficient in R. The key elements of the for loop would be something along the lines of:

```
master$unitstartpoint<-if(master$unitz)==1 0
master$unitstartpoint<-if(master$unitz)>1 master$unitstartpoint[i-1] + master$length[i-1]
```

i.e. the unit start point is 0 if it is the first in the z dimension, otherwise it is the start point of the prior unit + the length of the prior unit. Here's the data:

```
# generate dataframe
master<-c(rep(1,128),rep(2,128),rep(3,128),rep(4,128),rep(5,128))
master<-as.data.frame(master)

# input basic data--what load number the unit was in, where it was located 
# relative other units
master$boxNumber<-master$master
master$unitx<-rep(c(rep(1,32),rep(2,32),rep(3,32),rep(4,32)),5)
master$unity<-c(rep(1,8),rep(2,8),rep(3,8),rep(4,8))
master$unitz<-rep(1:8,80)

# create unique unit ID # based on load number and xyz coords.
transform(master,ID=paste0(boxNumber,unitx,unity,unitz))

# generate how long the unit is. this length will be used to identify unit
# location in the box
master$length<-round(rnorm(640,13,2))
```

I'm guessing there is a relatively easy way to do this with `apply` or `by` but I am unfamiliar with those functions.

Extra info: the unit ID's are unique and the master dataframe is sorted by boxNumber, unitx, unity, and then unitz, respectively.

This is what I am shooting for:

```
length unitx unity unitz unitstartpoint
15     1     1     1     0
14     1     1     2     15
11     1     1     3     29
13     1     1     4     40
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please add a small example of the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a cumulative sum along the z dimesion for each box/x/y combination. I used cumulative sum because otherwise if you reset at 0 when z=1 your definition would be leaving off the length at z=8. We can do this easily with `ave`

```
clength <- with(master, ave(length, boxNumber, unitx, unity, FUN=cumsum))
```

I'm exactly sure which values you want returned, but this column roughly transates to how you were redefining length above. If i combine with the original data and look at the total lenth for the first box for x=1, y=1:4

```
# head(subset(cbind(master, ml), unitz==8),4)

   master boxNumber unitx unity unitz length   ID  ml
8       1         1     1     1     8     17 1118 111
16      1         1     1     2     8     14 1128 104
24      1         1     1     3     8     10 1138  98
32      1         1     1     4     8     10 1148  99
```

we see the total lengths for those positions. Since we are using `cumsum` we are summing that the `z` are sorted as you have indicated they are. If you just want one total overall length per box/x/y combo, you can replace `cumsum` with `sum`.

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot, `ave` and `cumsum` are definitely much simpler than a for loop.